# Would you reformat a brand new external SSD (Samsung T5) or just use out-of-the-box

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, format, samsung-ssd

I just purchased a brand new 1Tb Samsung T5 SSD.
When I previously bought an external HDD, I often reformatted it, using NTFS or different sector sizes, etc. Maybe it just seemed the "cool nerdy thing to do" but whatever.

Does it still makes sense to completely reformat a new SSD, or shall I just start using it out-of-the-box?

I understood from a review that it is formatted with exFAT, but formatting with NTFS would be useful to use TRIM??

I will use this mostly as file back-up for main laptops (all Windows), and probably put photos and music on it as well, and I want to take it with me when I travel or go on vacation. I do not plan to encrypt it (maybe this is stupid?), as I am wary of the things that can go wrong (and yes, I did already forgot some passwords from zipfiles I created more than a decade ago... luckily nothing too important).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If out of the box it's in the format you need, then just use it.

If it isn't, then reformat.

It's quite likely to arrive as MBR/FAT (or ExFAT for a larger drive) which isn't much use to you if you need it to boot Windows or macOS, or if you need it to support more complex permissions systems or metadata (macOS ACLs, Windows Streams etc).

Comment: Thanks. It's exFat. Not needed to boot, but I read another forum thread where there were very strong opinions to use NTFS for a SSD drive. Only advantage I would see in exFat for my usecase would be that I could connect it directly to Android (but apparently this is not the case for all Android phones either).

Comment: Deciding **which** format for various uses would be an entirely different question - one I'm pretty sure has been asked on here before. Your question was **whether** to format.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's an implied secondary question, and I did not yet specifically search for that question on SU.
But anyway, if I would like to keep exFat, for you there is no advantage (reliability, robustness, etc.) to reformat myself vs. keeping the ex-factory formatting?

Comment: If there's nothing you need to change, there's no reason to reformat.

Answer (score 0):

Tetsujin answer is correct (Upvoted): You can use it as-is if the format is what you need.

The point to add is that the file-system is does not always determine the exact format and so you may have to format it even to use the same file-system if you want a different block-size, cluster-size, etc. Optimizing the FS to your use case can make a substantial difference in performance and space usage.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I see what you mean, and that's why previously I always reformatted. I'll do some additional searching to see whether I find the information I need.

Comment: Just another note that, there is nothing wrong with formatting it if you have doubts! Just format it the way you want it and you're done. In fact, it's a great moment to choose what type of partition table and how you want it partitioned.